# Integrate calculated AVG into same query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some troubles and hope you will help me. I need to calculate how many contracts there are in which hcb.sum:

1. <= 10k
2. greater than 10k but < AVG
3. greater than AVG

In the first case, everything is simple, but the problem arises when I need to count the following two cases: "> 10 but **< AVG**" and "**> AVG**". I can't solve this problem. How to integrate the calculated AVG into this query. Hope you understand what i need. Perhaps you can help me. Thanks in advance. Select is below:

```
SELECT  hcb.id AS 'ID'
    ,hcb.name AS 'Name'
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN hcb.kind = 'NEW' AND hcb.opt = 'CI' AND hcb.summ <= 10000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '<= 10k'
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN hcb.kind = 'NEW' AND hcb.opt = 'CI' AND hcb.summ BETWEEN 10000.01 AND **AVG** THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '> 10k < AVG'
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN hcb.kind = 'NEW' AND hcb.opt = 'CI' AND hcb.summ > **AVG** THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '> AVG'
    ,AVG(hcb.summ) AS 'AVG summ'
FROM DBO AS hcb
WHERE    hcb.stat IN (15, 20)
    AND hcb.optstat <> 2999
    AND hcb.opt = 'CI'
GROUP BY hcb.id, hcb.name
```

Comment: You cannot use nested aggregate fiunctions. Use either conditional window function or CTE/subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions.  Presumably, you want the average with the `where` conditions, so:

```
SELECT hcb.id AS id,
       hcb.name AS Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN hcb.kind = 'NEW' AND hcb.opt = 'CI' AND hcb.summ <= 10000
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS "<= 10k",
       SUM(CASE WHEN hcb.kind = 'NEW' AND hcb.opt = 'CI' AND hcb.summ > 10000 AND hcb.summ <= hcb.avg_summ 
               THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS "> 10k < AVG",
       SUM(CASE WHEN hcb.kind = 'NEW' AND hcb.opt = 'CI' AND hcb.summ > hcb.avg_summ
               THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS "> AVG",
       avg_summ
FROM (SELECT hcb.*,
             AVG(summ) OVER () as avg_summ
      FROM DBO AS hcb
      WHERE hcb.stat IN (15, 20) AND
            hcb.optstat <> 2999 AND
            hcb.opt = 'CI'
     ) hcb
GROUP BY hcb.id, hcb.name, avg_summ;
```

Note other changes to the query:

- The column aliases are defined using double quotes not single quotes.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants -- otherwise, you will one day have a confusion where you refer to a column using single quotes.
- The second `between` is removed, replaced with `>`, so values between 10000 and 10000.01 are included.
- If you want the overall average not subject to the filtering conditions, then move the `WHERE` conditions to the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

I have used 3 different joins and then in SELECT statement brought up 3 different values trough something like COALESCE(MAX(**d.[<10k]**),0) AS '<10k'

```
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT  r.id AS 'ID'
                ,COUNT(r.name) AS '<10k'
                FROM DBO as r
                WHERE   r.stat IN (15, 20)
                        AND r.optstat <> 2999
                        AND r.opt = 'CI'
                        AND r.kind = 'NEW'
                        AND r.summ BETWEEN 10000 AND (SELECT AVG(ci.summ)
                                                    FROM DBO as ci 
                                                    WHERE ci.stat IN (15, 20) 
                                                    AND ci.optstat <> 2999
                                                    AND ci.opt = 'CI'
                                                    AND ci.kind = 'NEW')
        GROUP BY r.id) AS d ON a.id = d.ID
```

Maybe it's not a best way to solve a problem, but it works for me. Thax a lot for some suggestions, they helped me. Cheers!